# Golang test mock functions best practices

Tags: testing, go

I am developing some tests for my code (using the *testing* package), and I am wondering what's the best way to mock functions inside the tested function:

Should I pass the function as parameter?
In that case, what if that function calls another function? Should I pass both the first and second function as parameters in the tested one?

Note: some of the functions are called on objects (i.e. someObj.Create()) and use HTTP API calls.

UPDATE for clarification:

Example: functions

```
func f1() error {
  ... //some API call
}

func (s *SomeStruct) f2() error {
  return f1
}

func f3() error {
  return nil
}

func f4() error {
  ...
  err = obj.f2()
  ...
  err = f3()
  ...
}
```

For the above: if I want to test f4, what's the best way to mock f2 and f3?

If I pass f2 and f3 to f4 as parameters it would work, but then what for the f2 test? Should I pass f1 to f2 as parameter?

And if that's it, should then f4 have f1 as well in the parameters?

Comment: When you say mock functions inside the tested function, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Updated the question with an example. I hope it's clearer. I'm quite new to tests and I am not 100% sure even how to ask

Comment: You need to clarify more. Are these functions in the package you are testing?

Comment: f1 and f2 aren't in the tested package, f3 is (but in the actual code f2 is called in another function inside the tested package, so there is one more layer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a general guideline, functions aren't very mockable so its in our best interests to mock structs that implement a certain interface that may be passed into functions to test the different branches of code. See below for a basic example.

```
package a

type DoSomethingInterface interface {
    DoSomething() error
}


func DoSomething(a DoSomethingInterface) {
    if err := a.DoSomething(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error occurred")
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("no error occurred")
    return
}

package a_test

import (
    "testing"
    "<path to a>/a"
)

type simpleMock struct {
    err error
}

func (m *simpleMock) DoSomething() error {
    return m.err
}

func TestDoSomething(t *testing.T) {
    errorMock := &simpleMock{errors.New("some error")}
    a.DoSomething(errorMock)
    // test that "an error occurred" is logged

    regularMock := &simpleMock{}
    a.DoSomething(regularMock)
    // test "no error occurred" is logged
}
```

In the above example, you would test the `DoSomething` function and the branches that happens eg. you would create an instance of the mock with an error for one test case and create another instance of the mock without the error to test the other case. The respective cases are to test a certain string has been logged to standard out; in this case it would be `"error occurred"` when `simpleMock` is instantiated with an error and `"no error occurred"` when there `simpleMock` is not instantiated with an error.

This can of course be expanded to other cases eg. the `DoSomething` function actually returns some kind of value and you want to make an `assertion` on the value.

**Edit:**

I updated the code with the concern that the interface lives in another package. Note that the new updated code has a package `a` that contains the interface and the function under test and a package `a_test` that is merely a template of how to approach testing `a.DoSomething`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The problem is that the interface I need to use isn't in the same package I need to test. Is it possible to implement an interface in a different package? I am looking but can't find an example

Comment: Yes, you can still implement another interface in another package. Go is unlike Java in that it doesn't require an explicit "implements" to adhere to an interface, instead its actually more like duck typing in dynamic languages. All you have to do is have the same methods for the particular struct and that struct can be used to satisfy the interface that the function expects.

Comment: @Ciack404 I updated the code sample to template the interface code that may be of interest. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here but I'll explain how testing should be done in Go.

Lets say we have an application with the following directory hierarchy:

```
root/
  pack1/
    pack1.go
    pack1_test.go
  pack2/
    pack2.go
    pack2_test.go
  main.go
  main_test.go
```

We'll assume that `pack2.go` has the functions you want to test:

```
package pack2 

func f1() error {
  ... //some API call
}

func (s *SomeStruct) f2() error {
  return f1
}

func f3() error {
  return nil
}

func f4() error {
  ...
  err = obj.f2()
  ...
  err = f3()
  ...
}
```

Looks good so far. Now if you want to test the functions in pack2, you would create a file called `pack2_test.go`. All test files in go are named similarly (packagename_test.go). Now lets see the inside of a typical test for a package (pack2_test.go in this example):

```
package pack2

import (
  "testing"
  "fmt"
)

TestF1(*testing.T) {
  x := "something for testing"
  f1() // This tests f1 from the package "pact2.go"
}


TestF2(*testing.T) {
    y := new(somestruct) 
    y.f2() // tests f2 from package "pact2.go"
}


TestF3(*testing.T) {
   /// some code
   f3() // tests f3
}


TestF4(*testing.T) {
    /// code
    f3() // you get the gist
}
```

Let me explain. Notice how in pack2_test.go, the first line says that the package is `pack2`. In a nutshell, this means that we're in the "scope" of the package `pack2` and thus all the functions found in `pack2` can be called as if you're within `pack2`. Thats why, within the Testf* functions, we could've called the functions from `pack2`. Another thing to note is the imported package "testing". This helps with two things:

First, it provides some functionality for running tests. I won't go into that.
Second, it helps identify the functions that `go test` should run.

Now to the functions. Any function within a test package that has the prefix "Test" and the parameters "t *testing.T" (you can use "*testing.T" when you don't need to use the testing functionality) will be executed when you run  `go test`. You use the variable `t` to reference the testing functionality I mentioned. You can also declare functions without the prefix and call them within the prefixed functions.

So, if I go to my terminal and run `go test`, it will execute the functions you want to test, specified in `pack2_test.go`

You can learn more about testing [here](https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/12) and [here](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But what happens if a function in package2 is using a function (interface) from package1 that I need to mock? If I get it right in your example you test all functions in the same package, correct?

Comment: so you need to call a function from pack1? Do this:

 ` 
import pack1; pack1.Function() // calls the function

The function needs to be public though (begins with a uppercase letter).

Comment: But the question is how to mock pack1.Function(), since you don't want to run the real function from the pack1 package, but rather use a mocked version in order to control inputs and outputs.